# Prove for each non-negative number s, there exists a non-negative t such that s $\geq$ t

Tags: proof-writing, quantifiers

Statement to prove (or disprove with counter-example) is:

> "For each non-negative number $s$, there exists a non-negative $t$ such that $s \geq t$."

I am pretty sure this statement is true, but I do not really know a way to approach a proof for this statement. I don't know how to prove it for every non-negative number $s$.

Thanks.

Comment: Or you sure you have the question right?  Batman's answer shows that that is.... light.

Answer (score 2):

Just take $t=s$. It doesn't even matter what "non-negative" means for this to work! The same proof will apply for any other adjective.

Comment: (+1) It  only matters  that $s \geq t$ means $s > t$ or $ s = t$. We don't even have to know what $>$ means :)

Comment: Thanks, didn't see it this way, but it makes the most sense and is the simplest answer.

Answer (score 1):

Every non-negative number is greater than or equal to $0$. This is by definition of non-negativity. $0$ itself is non-negative (since $0 \geq 0$).

Answer (score 0):

If $s \ge 0$ take $t=s/2$. Then $t \ge 0$ and $s \ge t$.